# Simple MySQL database structure question

Tags: mysql

This is something I should really know, but I haven't done any db work for quite a while and just wanted some clarification on a structure for a simple mysql database.

The basic premise is a shopping cart - so we have catalogue, customer and orders.For now, the customer isn't going to sign up, they will enter details every time.

My main struggle is how to structure the customer and order table as obviously it would be good to have these separate.

Is the best method just to have the customer table with an fkey to the order table, and the order table simply references the item in the catalogue with another fkey?

Any clarification is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 tables at the very basic level: `users`, `basket`, `items`, `basket_items`.

Orders would work just like `basket` and `basket_items` so let's keep it simple for now.

A Record in `basket_items` is just a `basket_id` and an `item_id` - it's a [link table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) used for resolving this kind of many-to-many relationship (each `basket` has many `items`, each `item` can be in many `baskets`).

The `basket` or `orders` table, as you say, just have a foreign key to the `customers` table - each order is by one, and only one customer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have an `orders` table, in which new user session (or log in, later) a new order will be created. It will contain the `customer_id`, the quantity of items, the `item_id` (fkey) and the total (calculated dynamically if you wanted to)

Comment: The bit im struggling with is there can be more than one item in the basket and I don't want to be comma separating them.

Comment: The `orders` table can't contain IDs of all the items. You need a separate `order_items` table to link the two.

Comment: of course it's not convenient, but it will contain the item_id linked with the item table and the quantity of the order.